# Alignment buttons greyed out in Sketch

Tags: sketch-app, alignment

I am teaching remotely sketch, but one of my mentees says that he cant use the alignment tools, they always appear greyed out even when he already selected multiple shapes. Any idea what is causing this? Have anybody experience something like this before? 
Here is a screenshot of how it looks on his end.
[image]

Comment: I think you should contact [Sketch support](https://www.sketchapp.com/support/).

Answer (score 1):

You did not create an artboard.I am not sure but try to create an artboard first.
for creating artboard, hit "A" button.